# Формула-шаблон и ее последующий просчёт

Tags: c#, winforms, математика

Имеется формула,[image] делал визуальное приложение, вроде бы по коду все верно написал, но ответ разнится с тем что представлен на скриншоте.

[image]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _2._8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double x = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            double y = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            double z = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            double o;


            o = (Math.Exp(x - y) * Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x - y), (x + y))) / (Math.Atan(x) + Math.Atan(z)) + Math.Pow(Math.Pow(x, 6) + Math.Pow(Math.Log(y), 2), 1 / 3);


            textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать в чём ошибка, и как можно ее исправить.

Comment: Один модуль потеряли, а так отладчик вам поможет

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, а то голову уже сломал, тоже сейчас пригляделся, и правда, потерял, еще раз спасибо!